# Разделение одной картинки на 3 части

Tags: javascript, html, css

Увидел на сайте разделение одной картинки на три разных блока, как это реализуется?

### Три картинки в одной

[image: Три картинки в одной]

### Блоки на сайте

[image: Блоки на сайте]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [спрайты](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-sprite). Используется для сокращения количества обращений к серверу.

Допустим у нас есть спрайт размеров 32px x 64px, состоящий из двух картинок размером 32px x 32px.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #pic1 {
            /* размеры картинки */
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
            background: url(sprite.png);

            /* смещение картинки */
            background-position: 0 0;
        }

        #pic2 {
            /* размеры картинки */
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
            background: url(sprite.png);

            /* смещение картинки */
            background-position: 0 32px;
        }
    </style
</head>
<body>
    <p id="pic1"/>
    <p id="pic1"/>
</body>
</html>
```